# Pass data between ViewController and ContainerViewController

Tags: swift, swift2, segue, uistoryboardsegue, swift-protocols

I'm working on an app, and need to pass data between view and containerView. I need to send data and receive data from both Views.

Let me explain better:

I can change the **Label Master** (Touch the Container Button) by **protocol**, but I can not change the **Label Container** (Touch the Master button). What happens is the Master connects with the container by a following. But do not have a follow Container linking to the Master.

I tried to add but segue to, but it worked.

[image]

The Master View Controller:

```
import UIKit

protocol MasterToContainer {
    func changeLabel(text:String)
}

class Master: UIViewController, ContainerToMaster {

    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!

    var masterToContainer:MasterToContainer?

    @IBOutlet var labelMaster: UILabel!


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "containerViewSegue" {
            let view = segue.destinationViewController as? Container
            view!.containerToMaster = self
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func button_Container(sender: AnyObject) {
        masterToContainer?.changeLabel("Nice! It's work!")
    }


    func changeLabel(text: String) {
        labelMaster.text = text
    }
}
```

The Container View Controller:

```
import UIKit

protocol ContainerToMaster {
    func changeLabel(text:String)
}

class Container: UIViewController, MasterToContainer {

    var containerToMaster:ContainerToMaster?

    @IBOutlet var labelContainer: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func button_Master(sender: AnyObject) {
        containerToMaster?.changeLabel("Amazing! It's work!")
    }


    func changeLabel(text: String) {
        labelContainer.text = text
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What if you store the values you want to send by using NSUserDefaults?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to use protocols, but have not found anything yet. How could use NSUserDefaults to pass this data?

Comment: looking for same solution in objective-c

Answer (score 33, accepted):

All you need to do is keep a reference to `Container` in your master view controller.

That is, you should add an instance variable to `Master` that will hold a reference to the **view controller**, not just the view. You'll need to set it in `prepareForSegue`.

So the beginning of Master View Controller would look something like this:

```
class Master: UIViewController, ContainerToMaster {

@IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!

var containerViewController: Container?

@IBOutlet var labelMaster: UILabel!

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "containerViewSegue" {
        containerViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? Container
        containerViewController!.containerToMaster = self
    }
}
```

And then in your button function, simply change the label using the variable you just added.

Example:

```
@IBAction func button_Container(sender: AnyObject) {
    containerViewController?.changeLabel("Nice! It's work!")
}
```

This means you can get rid of your `MasterToContainer` protocol too.

I tested this code, so I know it works, but unfortunately I am an Objective-C dev, and know nothing about best practices in Swift. So I don't know if this is the best way to go about it, but it certainly works.

**Edit:**

Here's the exact code I've tested:

Master.swift:

```
import UIKit

class Master: UIViewController, ContainerToMaster {

    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var labelMaster: UILabel!
    var containerViewController: Container?

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "containerViewSegue" {
            containerViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? Container
            containerViewController!.containerToMaster = self
        }
    }

    @IBAction func button_Container(sender: AnyObject) {
        containerViewController?.changeLabel("Nice! It's work!")
    }

    func changeLabel(text: String) {
        labelMaster.text = text
    }
}
```

Container.swift:

```
import UIKit

protocol ContainerToMaster {
    func changeLabel(text:String)
}

class Container: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var labelContainer: UILabel!
    var containerToMaster:ContainerToMaster?

    @IBAction func button_Master(sender: AnyObject) {
        containerToMaster?.changeLabel("Amazing! It's work!")
    }

    func changeLabel(text: String) {
        labelContainer.text = text
    }
}
```

Comment: That's basically what I have.I must connect the Master with the Container. But I do not have a follow back.

Comment: @James Downvote? Seriously? I'm trying to help you here. What do you mean by "I do not have a follow back"? As I understand it, you want the button in `Master` to change the label in `Container`. Is that not right?

Comment: Downvote: Apparently, you got the code I posted an example and me "taught to use".
What I need: I need a view to send data to another I just have one segue, linking the Master to the container, so the container can "communicate" by the master protocol. I need the Container "is cominique" with the Master.

Comment: @James I can barely understand you, but I updated my answer with the full code of what I tested. `Master` is able to send data to `Container` using the variable `containerViewController`, and `Container` is able to send data to `Master` using the `containerToMaster` variable, which conforms to the `ContainerToMaster` protocol. I think the piece you were missing was setting your variable in `prepareForSegue` rather than using a constant.

Comment: Excuse me for my English, I am Brazilian. And that question is the fourth question what I do to get the result I really need. Thanks for the answer, and apologize for Downvote.

Comment: @James No worries! Best of luck to you with everything. A bit of advice moving forward: make sure you fully understand the difference between a view and a view controller. What you're really doing here is passing data between view controllers, and those view controllers pass the data to their respective views.

Comment: This is a solid solution.

Comment: I tried this but `prepareForSegue` is not called... Rob's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 29):

I solved it with this code

To send data from ViewController -> ContainerViewController

```
Class ViewController : UIViewController {

func sendData(MyStringToSend : String) {

let CVC = childViewControllers.last as! ContainerViewController
CVC.ChangeLabel( MyStringToSend)
}

}
```

in your ContainerViewController

```
Class ContainerViewController : UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

func ChangeLabel(labelToChange : String){

myLabel.text = labelToChange

 }
}
```

To send data from ContainerViewController -> ViewController

```
Class ContainerViewController : UIViewController {

func sendDataToVc(myString : String) {

   let Vc = parentViewController as! ViewController
   Vc.dataFromContainer(myString)
 }

}
```

and in ViewController

```
  Class ViewController : UIViewController {

  func dataFromContainer(containerData : String){

   print(containerData)
  }

  }
```

I hope this will help someone.

Comment: Thanks rob pretty simple and clean.

Comment: what is it childViewControllers ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this extension to access the container child

```
extension UIViewController {
  func getContainerChild<vc:UIViewController>(_ viewController : vc,_ hasNavigation : Bool = true) -> (vc) {
    guard let vc = self.children[0] as? UINavigationController else {return viewController}
    if hasNavigation {
        guard let childVC = vc.children[0] as? PurchasedHistoryListVC else {
            return viewController}
        return childVC as! vc
    } else {
        return vc as! vc
    }
   }
}
```

so you can do some thing like this in your view Controller

```
let vc = self.getContainerChild(yourChildViewControllerClass())
vc.functionName()
```