# Swift: How to pass data to PageViewController which is embedded in ContainerView?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

VC **A** has a container view with a VC **B** that has two VC's: **C** and **D**.

**B** is the DataSource for **C** and **D**

I want to update labels in **C** and **D** directly from **A**

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34349405/4286947) answer about passing data between Master View Controller and Container.

However, in my case I cannot keep reference to the controllers in **A**, because they are created dynamically inside DataSource methods in **B**

Should I keep reference to **B** and pass data through delegate, then pass data forward from **B** to **C** and **D** using delegate again?

How should I approach such problem, is there a better way to design it?

To give you a better idea of what I want to achieve, have a look at this screenshot from `Runkeeper` app

[image]

Both distance and pace labels are embedded in container view with a page view controller.

Comment: I used static instance and it works great for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow during my own brainstorm on this problem, I found out that I ommited the most straightforward solution:

1) Create **C** and **D** instances inside **A**

2) Pass them to **B** using `prepareForSegue` method

3) In **B** assign them to according VC's

4) Voila, I can access  their variables and functions right from **A**

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1:**

My solutions would be to throw **B** away and make **A** the datasource.

I would write an Swift extension (if you are using Swift) and just put all the datasource methods in it. Then **A** can access **C** & **D** normally.

**SOLUTION 2:**

If you can't remove **B** then I would make a Model Class which has the data for **C**s and **D**s labels.

This model class can be inside:

A) DataManager which conforms to the Singleton pattern

B) static class

C) UserDefaults, DataBase (just food for thought)

**C** and **D** would be alerted in Model changes via the Observer pattern (`NSNotificationCenter`)