# UI in Container View is not updating

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uilabel, uicontainerview

I have a view with buttons, when the user presses the button a container view is displayed. I use:

```
ContainerView.setNeedsDisplay()
```

to update the container view. I do this because I have UI such as a label and I want the text to be based on what button is clicked.

The issue is that whilst the view is being updated, and the text is being updated, the label text does not change.

Comment: Look my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37748737/3108877

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Rroobb for your comment, that works! - stackoverflow.com/a/37748737/3108877

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Helper that does just this, source may help you:

```
+ (void)navigateFromController:(UIViewController *)fromController toController:(UIViewController *)toController {
    if (fromController) {
        // Remove any existing child controllers.
        for (UIViewController *child in [toController childViewControllers]) {
            [child willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
            [child.view removeFromSuperview];
            [child removeFromParentViewController];
        }

        // Embed the new controller.
        [fromController addChildViewController:toController];

        toController.view.frame = fromController.view.bounds;
        toController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        [fromController.view addSubview:toController.view];

        [toController.view.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:fromController.view.leftAnchor].active = YES;
        [toController.view.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:fromController.view.rightAnchor].active = YES;
        [toController.view.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:fromController.view.topAnchor].active = YES;
        [toController.view.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:fromController.view.bottomAnchor].active = YES;

        [fromController didMoveToParentViewController:fromController];
    }
}
```