# UIPickerView passing data to Container View

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have looked through some container view questions on StacksOverflow but none is using picker view to pass data to my tableview cell in containerview. I have tried using:

```
    func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "containerSettingsSegue" {
            let destination = segue.destination as! SettingsTableViewController
            destination.delegate = self
            destination.languageDetail.text = myPickerData[row]
        }
    }
}
```

and also

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "containerSettingsSegue" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! SettingsTableViewController
        destination.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Both codes above are in my parent view.

However, it isnt working. Is there any ways I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @TBlank for the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34349405/1142743

So as per his answer code should be like below:

Declare a instance of `SettingsTableViewController` in `SettingsViewController` like :

```
var childView : SettingsTableViewController?


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "containerSettingsSegue" {
            childView = segue.destination as? SettingsTableViewController
            childView!.delegate = self
        }


     }


func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            childView?.changeLabel(text: myPickerData[row])
    }
```

So now declare a method in `SettingsTableViewController` like below

```
func changeLabel(text: String) {
        languageDetail.text = text
    }
```

Comment: i declared a var selectedRow = 0, and the rest as follow, but it crashed..saying 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value'

Comment: it crashed at the line of '            destination.languageDetail.text = myPickerData[selectedRow]
' and in languageDetail, at viewdidload of the SettingsTableViewController, i set it to 'English'

Comment: have sent you the specific files

Comment: it's a container view, embedded in it is a tableview

Comment: have mailed you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194742/discussion-between-vinodh-and-l-william).

Comment: i am starting to understand your meaning. But when i breakpoint on the didselectrow, on childview, it shows nil after i select the data...seems like it's not detecting the childview

Comment: changed a line in the code...to children.last..it works now..thank you so much for the help..unsure why children.last works though